# Correcting nonsense digits during data import

Tags: import, data, digits

I import large amounts of data, and for whatever reason the data in cases add large numbers of either '0s' or '9s'. However, as the numbers have very different relevant digits, I cannot simply use NumberForm to define the number of digits. One example of the problem is shown below, but it could also be, e.g., 102.0000000000003 or 56.99999999998.
I could come up with some complicated rules, but I hope for a simpler solution.

The data are running through a script for some other corrections, in this step, I'd like to also correct these nonsense digits.

[image]

One example where it still does not work:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how you are importing this data, particularly the actual code you're using and the format of the data? This is a floating point issue.

Comment: The data are copied from a website to an Excel file, from which this is then imported.

Comment: See [`Round`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Round.html).

Comment: I tried Round, but doesn't work in this case, as it needs specific parameters, but I need a flexible solution.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to change these numbers? For computaiton, it should not be needed. Is it for display only? Why does NumberForm not work for you? Can you give specific examples where NumberForm does not give you the desired display?

Comment: Further to what @Szabolcs noted, some numbers have short exact representations in base 10 but not in binary. A consequence for finite binary representations is that they may not perfectly "round-trip"; output of the closest base 10 value of comparable precision might be slightly different from input. By the way, this will not happen with values that are decimal renditions of integers, such as 102.0 or 57.000.

Comment: @Szabolcs The full digits are analytical data and in fact nonsense/artifact. I don't know why they appear (maybe a problem of the data provider). So these are only misleading and annoying.

Comment: The reason is what Daniel said. You know that 1/3 cannot be written in full in decimal: it would require an infinite number of digits. 0.3333 is not 1/3. The same is true for 1/5 = 0.2 in binary. You have numbers like 0.0671 in your list. Those cannot be represented exactly. It's going to have to be either 0.06710000000000001 or 0.06709999999999999. The program you are importing from seems to have chosen the latter for you.

Comment: Agreed, but this is a website with data from publications, there should not be any such numbers. But maybe you are right and that is the problem – Now I only need a solution to delete all these needless digits.

Comment: Some kind of rounding, but I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know the internals of Mathematica but I noticed that `ToString` removes digits after a second group of zeroes. Try this code.

```
    inp = {0.00008200000000000003`, 0.333333333333333312`, 
    0.2333999999999999976`};
    ToExpression[RowBox[{ToString[#]}]] & /@ inp // FullForm
```

---

**Previous answer**

The function `N@Rationalize[#, 10^(-$MachinePrecision + 5)] &` seems to do the trick.

```
    inp = {0.006000000000000538`, 0.0025800000002995675`, 
   0.19899999999989948`, 1/3} ;
    N@Rationalize[#, 10^(-$MachinePrecision + 5)] & /@ inp // FullForm
    (*List[0.006`,0.00258`,0.199`,0.3333333333333333`]*)
```

`$MachinePrecision` is basically the number of digits that your machine uses internally. The exponent `-$MachinePrecision + 5` says that the denominator of `Rationalize` should have that number of digits.

Comment: Actually, `Chop` did not do anything here. It either replaces a number by zero, or it leaves it alone. What you see here is the lower default display precision in Output cells than in Input ones.

Comment: Szabolcs is correct, as soon as you look at the output in full it is the same as before. I also tried Chop.

Comment: @MockupDungeon, the answer with Chop was incorrect. Have you tried the one with Rationalize?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked it. I have to test it a little more, but it looks good so far!

Comment: OK, I think this seems to work. I had to make a MachinePrecision of +6 for the large numbers and -7 for the small numbers. I couldn't fully understand how MachinePrecision works, but build in a test in case the new and old value are significantly different. I hope, I don't input some new artifacts ...

Comment: ... at least in about 90% of the cases, still not always.

Comment: @MockupDungeon, I added a small explanation for the rationale of the answer. Could you post a number for which the answer does not do what you expect?

Comment: Sure! I've done this above.